# Windows Phone: Performance issues using xml to load my page data?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, xna, windows-phone-7.1

WP7.5/ Silverlight app. This is a story book type app.

I am in a process to refactor my code. So I created a base storypage class. The core story pages are almost similar with back/next/home buttons on it. What differs on each page is images, animations, some text and sounds played on the click of images.

I plan to store story specific data into an XML file. So on each page NavigatedTo, I load my objects and initialize variables with the data from xml. I pass the storypageId to grab appropriate element from the XML.

**My Question:**

- Is it a good way to go? or do you see any issues with this.
- A typical story consists of about 15-20 pages. So basically my XML will have 15-20 Page elements. I will be reading XML on each page load. Can this cause any performance issue?
- In future the app will have more stories. So would it be a good idea to store all stories in one XML or is it good to go one XML per story. My major concern is any performance implications as the size of XML will grow.

Has anyone come across such situation and can share their experience.
Any ideas / suggestions welcome. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I think XML is fine for storing the data, but if you pre-load the next page it will hide the loading delay from the normal reader. The idea would be to always try to have the current page, the next page and the previous page in memory. Then depending on memory use, you could even pre-load the next 2 or 3 pages.

Comment: How do I preload the next page in memory? I do have memory constraints so I actually clear the backstack, else the previous page always stayed in memory.

Comment: It depends on how your data is stored in the xml. It sounds like you could load all the xml at once, and then pull out the page objects and load them as needed.